# Install Vanilla Android Lollipop on Insignia Flex 8" NS-14T002

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rom-flashing, tablet, 5.1-lollipop, vanilla-android

I have an Insignia Flex 8" NS-14T002 tablet which I have successfully rooted using KingoRoot. The device is currently running Android 4.4.2 KitKat stock ROM provided by the manufacturer. I wish to upgrade it to the next level, i.e., install vanilla Android 5.1.1 Lollipop.

But unfortunately ClockworkMod doesn't support the device. So I am unsure how to install the ROM into my tab as I have never done so before. Also, is there a separate vanilla ROM for each device?

Can someone give a step by step procedure of how to install a ROM manually without CWM?

Please comment in case you need any further details.

Comment: There is a CWM recovery [here](http://d-h.st/Tng) for your device. Besides, clockworkmod.com only mentions those devices on the website which are officially supported. The link I mentioned is an [unofficial port](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2548838&page=2). [This one](http://androidforums.com/threads/guide-how-to-install-cwm-insignia-flex-8-ns-14t002.825577/)  is another tutorial for CWM. As for finding a custom ROM, somebody else perhaps can help here. Good luck!

Comment: @Firelord: I came across this one. Have the CWM downloaded with me. But how am I supposed to use it? Should I directly install it like ROM Manager or is there some other procedure for it? Also, the file is a `.img` file. How am I supposed to use it?

Comment: If your device supports flashing from fastboot, then boot into fastboot and enter `fastboot flash recovery <YOUR FILE>`. If not, then you can use `adb` and `dd`to flash recovery partition. The easiest is to use a tool like [Rashr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mkrtchyan.recoverytools) or [Flashify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.flashify&hl=en). **Caution: Take backup always, I can't stress this more.**

Comment: Also, I did mention (in my first comment) [this tutorial](http://androidforums.com/threads/guide-how-to-install-cwm-insignia-flex-8-ns-14t002.825577/) for flashing CWM.

Comment: @Firelord: Thanks for the information. I'll try running this and keep you posted if it works fine.